# ¿Como llenar un combobox en c++ mfc con id y descripcion?

Tags: c++

Tengo esta funcion que llena el combobox en C++ mfc pero no se como guardar el id y la descripcion en el combobox, ya que actualmente lo hace con la pura descripcion.
En c# se utiliza un objeto pairvalue para hacer esto, pero no le encuentro c++ mfc. si alguien pudiera guiarme.

```
bool CDlgSolicitudes::fObtenerCompradores()
{
CString sConsulta;
bool bRegresa=false;


if( odbc.Open("PostgreSQL", g.server, g.user, g.password , g.database) )
{
    sConsulta.Format("select numempleado, nombreempleado from fun_inconsultarcompradores()");

    CConsultarCompradores crSQL( &odbc );
    if( crSQL.Exec( sConsulta ) )
    {

        m_cbCompradores.InsertString(-1, "Selecciona un comprador");
        crSQL.activarCols();
        while( crSQL.Leer() )
        {
            CString nomComprador;
            nomComprador.Format("%s",crSQL.nomComprador);
            nomComprador = nomComprador.Trim();
            m_cbCompradores.AddString(nomComprador);

        }
        bRegresa = true;
        odbc.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        crSQL.odbc->GetLastError(crSQL.GetHstmt()); 
        CString error;
        error.Format("[fObtenerCompradores] %s", crSQL.odbc->m_szErrorMsg);
        odbc.Close();
        AfxMessageBox(error);
    }
}
else
{
    CString error;
    error.Format("[fObtenerCompradores] %s", odbc.m_szErrorMsg);
    odbc.Close();
    AfxMessageBox(error);
}

    return bRegresa;
}
```

Ejemplo:
Si a mi la función fun_inconsultarcompradores() me obtiene lo siguiente:
435 - COMPRADOR 1
778 - COMPRADOR 2
921 - COMPRADOR 3

Por lo tanto el combo lo voy a llenar con las descripciones:
COMPRADOR 1
COMPRADOR 2
COMPRADOR 3

Pero si yo quiero guardar en bd el comprador seleccionado, pero nada mas el numero, como le puedo hacer si en el combo nada mas tengo la descripción.

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola!
  Imagino que con ID te refieres al identificador que identifica (perdón por la redundancia) el elemento dentro del ComboBox y en efecto sólo tienes las funciones miembro *InsertString* y *AddString* y que luego para obtener cada uno de los miembros se utiliza el *FindStringExact*, *FindString* y el *GetLBText* sabiendo el ordinal del elemento. Pero en principio esto no debería darte problemas ¿no? ya que la seleccionar el elemento del ComboBox la función te devuelve el ordinal de éste mediante *GetCurSel* y con éste acceder al contenido seleccionado mediante *GetLBText (GetCurSel(), valor)*.
Espero que te ayude
Ánimo

Comment: Si no añades algo de código la respuesta queda excesivamente floja. Piensa que es posible que para ti sea algo obvio, pero si te pones en el lugar de quien pregunta porque no sabe hacerlo la cosa cambia.

Comment: Vamos a suponer que tengo un combo y al seleccionar una opción quiero que al dar click en guardar, me guarde la id de esa opción, como le hago si en el combobox solo guardo la descripcion.

Comment: Al dar click sobre la opción de ese combo, haces una llamada a _GetCurSel()_ (https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev15.query?appId=Dev15IDEF1&l=ES-ES&k=k(%22AFXWIN%2FCComboBox%3A%3AGetCurSel%22);k(%22CComboBox%3A%3AGetCurSel%22);k(GetCurSel);k(DevLang-C%2B%2B);k(TargetOS-Windows)&rd=true)que te devuelve la posición de esa opción en el combo Box, o lo que es lo mismo, su ID.  Una vez tienes su ID (o nº de opción en el combo) puedes obtener el contenido del mismo haciendo _GetLBText (ID, valor);_

Comment: Todo en una instrucción sería:  **CComboBox   combo;  int ID = combo.GetCurSel();  /*para obtener el valor (valor_o_descripcion)*/ combo.GetLBText (ID, valor_o_descripcion);**